# How to test Material2 snack-bar?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-material2, angular-test

I have a project on Angular 5 and I encountered with following issue. I have a 
component ComponentWithSnackBar which triggers displaying of a snack-bar:

```
showSnackBar() {
  this.snackBar.open('Message text', 'Close', {
    duration: 5000,
    verticalPosition: 'top',
  });
}
```

It works as expected. But I have no ideas how I can test it. I try to write test:

```
describe('ComponentWithSnackBar', () => {
  let snackBar: MatSnackBar;
  let overlayContainer: OverlayContainer;
  let overlayContainerElement: HTMLElement;

  function createComponent<T>(component: Type<T>, providers: Provider[] = [], declarations: any[] = []): ComponentFixture<T> {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule, RouterTestingModule, NoopAnimationsModule],
      declarations: declarations,
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
      providers,
    }).compileComponents();

    inject([MatSnackBar, OverlayContainer], (sb: MatSnackBar, oc: OverlayContainer) => {
      snackBar = sb;
      overlayContainer = oc;
      overlayContainerElement = oc.getContainerElement();
    })();

    return TestBed.createComponent<T>(component);
  }

  it(`Should display snack-bar`, fakeAsync(() => {
    const fixture = createComponent(ComponentWithSnackBar);
    const component: ComponentWithSnackBar = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;

    fixture.detectChanges();
    const button = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button')); //button which triggers method showSnackBar 
    button.triggerEventHandler('click', null);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    flush();

    const messageElement = overlayContainerElement.querySelector('snack-bar-container');
    expect(messageElement.textContent).toContain('Message text');
  }));
});
```

As a result I get error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null

What I do wrong? Thanks for advance!

Answer (score 7):

The following worked for me:

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;
  let element: any;
  let overlayContainer: OverlayContainer;
  let overlayContainerElement: HTMLElement;
  let snackBar: MatSnackBar;

....

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    element = fixture.nativeElement;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

beforeEach(inject([MatSnackBar, OverlayContainer],
    (sb: MatSnackBar, oc: OverlayContainer) => {
      snackBar = sb;
      overlayContainer = oc;
      overlayContainerElement = oc.getContainerElement();
    }));

....

 it('should show my success message', () => {
      
   const containerElement = overlayContainerElement.querySelector('simple-snack-bar');
   
   expect(containerElement.textContent).toContain('My success text');
 });
```

Comment: The Github link in the preamble is dead @dgraf

Comment: @Milton thanx, i deleted it, because it is no longer accessible

Answer (score 1):

I decided do not test fact of displaying of snack-bar, but only fact of call method `snackBar.open()` with correct arguments:

```
expect(snackBarSpy.open.calls.count()).toEqual(1);
expect(snackBarSpy.open.calls.first().args).toEqual([message, 'Close', {duration: 5000, verticalPosition: 'top'}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue when trying to test a component with a material dialog. I didn't find the solution but I figured I'd share what I do know:

If you put a breakpoint on the test when running and inspect the scope, the `overlayContainerElement` (which is the div with the class `cdk-overlay-container`) has no child nodes.

Also if you add the following to the end of the test before the expect statement:

```
console.log("overlay wrapper", document.getElementsByClassName('cdk-global-overlay-wrapper')[0]);
// and or
console.log("snackbar text", document.getElementsByClassName('snack-bar-container')[0]); // or whatever class you gave this item
```

They both log undefined.

My theory is that Angular change detection does not get run on the components that are involved with displaying material parts such as the dialog or snackbar which is why they are empty/not showing during the test.

Can you also share the code for the ComponentWithSnackBar?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, ComponentWithSnackBar is not real component. It`s just simplified version of my component. 
I think, your have a correct theory.

Answer (score -1):

```
const mockSnackbar = jasmine.createSpyObj(['open']);

it('test desc'()=>{
    component.showSnackBar()
        expect(mockSnackbar.open).tohavebeencalled();
        expect(mockSnackbar.open).tohavebeencalledwith('Message text',
            'Close', {
                duration: 5000,
                verticalPosition: 'top',
            });
})
```